# Val_loss "Nan" After Decreasing Sample Size in the CSV File but Processed Data Is the Same

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, tf.keras, google-prediction

I have tried the following [example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/), which works very well. In the example file, the values are stored in 10-minute intervals. However, since I need to bring in more values that are just hourly available, I deleted from the database all values that were not at a full hour. Say: There are now only 1/6 as many rows and three more columns that are not selected in this test run so far.

If I now execute the code exactly as before, the following step will return

```
path_checkpoint = "model_checkpoint.h5"
es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0, patience=5)

modelckpt_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    monitor="val_loss",
    filepath=path_checkpoint,
    verbose=1,
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_best_only=True,
)

history = model.fit(
    dataset_train,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=dataset_val,
    callbacks=[es_callback, modelckpt_callback],
)
```

always the message the val_loss error for each epoch:

```
Epoch 1/10
871/871 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4529
Epoch 1: val_loss did not improve from inf
871/871 [==============================] - 288s 328ms/step - loss: 0.4529 - val_loss: nan
```

I think it is related to this previous code block,

```
split_fraction = 0.715
train_split = int(split_fraction * int(df.shape[0]))
step = 6

past = 720
future = 72
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 256
epochs = 10


def normalize(data, train_split):
    data_mean = data[:train_split].mean(axis=0)
    data_std = data[:train_split].std(axis=0)
    return (data - data_mean) / data_std
```

where the original author specifies that only every sixth record should be used. Since I already removed every sixth record before, it should now use all records. Therefore I already tried to set step = 1, but without success. It still comes with the message that **val_loss did not improve from inf**

Does anyone know what else I would need to adjust to satisfy the code that I now have only one-sixth as many rows as originally thought? The result should initially end up with the same values as in the example because I have not yet used the new data.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was inside the .csv file.
In two of the 300000 rows, the date was formatted as 25.10.**18**, but in the other rows, the time was 25.10.**2018**.

After editing the format to a consistent dd.mm.yyyy, the val_loss decreased as expected.

If you are facing the same issue, this code can help you to find wrong formatted rows:

`date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date Time'), format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')`